# Wake On LAN for Windows PC

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter, wake-on-lan

I have `Asus PRIME H470-PLUS` motherboard with plugged in `Intel PCI` network card [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FZYZVX2). Trying to configure WOL for current PC on local network. I was trying to wake up PC from others PC on local network, but current PC is not starting. I set `Power On By PCI-E` to `Enabled` in Bios according to [manual](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045950/).

Did required settings in network card driver by checking "Allow this device to wake the computer".

[image]

In order to wake up Windows software,  DDWRT router, Android application was used.

I was trying to enter PC's IP address, network, broadcast address, UDP port 7 and 9 and PC's network card MAC address.

[image]

What else I can do in order to solve this problem?

UPD

Uncheck `Allow to turn off this device to save power` disables `Allow this device to wake the computer`

[image]

Comment: Is WOL working with onboard LAN which is generally built into the board? Uncheck Allow to turn off this device to save power.

Comment: Uncheck `Allow to turn off this device to save power` disables `Allow this device to wake the computer`

Comment: Onboard card is damaged and I can't check WOL with it